# C++ std::map vs dynamic array

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, time-complexity

I'm trying to make a 3 dimensional array of booleans that tells me if I previously visited a location in 3d space for a simple navigation algorithm. The array could be quite large (something along the lines of 1,000,000 x 1,000,000 x 1,000,000 or maybe larger), so I'm wondering if it would be faster to declare an array of that size and set each boolean value to false, or to make a map with a key of coordinate (x, y, z) and a value of type bool.

From what I figure, the array would take O(1) to find or modify a coordinate, and the map would take O(log n) to find or insert a value. Obviously, for accessing values, the array is faster. However, does this offset the time it takes to declare such an array?

Thanks

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is on average O(1)

Comment: Why not use a hash map (`unordered_map` in C++11)?

Comment: Even at one bit per cell you'd need over 10^11 GB of memory for an array. You should probably think about a better approach.

Comment: Speed is the wrong optimization to be concerned with at the moment.

Comment: How many elements do you expect to be set in your array? If you eventually expect to visit all cells using a compact representation of the array (e.g. using one bit per cell rather than a `bool`) might be the best approach. If you expect to visit paths the smaller memory footprint of a set or a hash set (`std::unordered_set`; you can determine the value by the presence of an element) can offset the better access patterns.

Comment: @DavidO Yes, fair point :P

Didn't see unordered_set. I'm going to try that for now.

Comment: I'm guessing it's going to be a lot cheaper (memory) to store all visited coordinates, rather than storing a bool for every possible coordinate.  Imagine if that Garmin etrex maintained its breadcrumb trail by storing one bit per ever five square feet of planet earth.

Comment: For the record, I ended up using an unordered_set. It suits my needs perfectly. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I know this is late (so I'm guessing I'm not going to get a response), but I think a vector might be faster.

I know the dimensions of the 3d space at start, and it turns out that I was wrong about the maximum size (assume that it will always fit in memory). I can make a vector of bools with initial dimensions of the 3d space, and then reading and changing the bools takes O(1) time.

So my question is, on average, is it faster to initialize this vector of bools and then have O(1) access time, or to add ints to an unordered_set as I need them (0 time to initialize)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even at 1 bit per bool, your array will take over 2**39 bytes. I'd suggest a `set` if there aren't too many elements that will be `true`.

You can use a class to hide the implementation details, and use a 1D set.

Comment: This seems like one of the few use cases where `std::set` is the ideal data structure, since all you care about is "Have I been here?". The "implementation details" class would have 3 data members (the x, y, and z coordinates) and define `operator <`. Depending on your use case, the only other thing you might need is a constructor that accepts the x, y, and z coordinates, with the data members private (if all you really ever care about for these coordinates is whether you've been there).

Comment: Is that any faster than std::unordered_set?

On that note, I've been having trouble figuring out what functions I need to implement in my class (which just contains three int values) to allow usage with an unordered_set.

Comment: @VerTiGo_Etrex, the speed difference between `std::set` and `std::unsorted_set` will depend on the number of elements you have populated and the quality of your hash function. `std::set` requires a `<` comparator, and `std::unordered_set` requires a hash function and a `==` comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calculating how much memory would be needed for an array like this? A lot!
Use std::map if ordering of the points is important, or std::unordeded_map if not. Also the unordered map gives you a constant time insertion and lookup.
I guess that some kind of search tree is probably what you're looking for (k-d tree for example).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to make an array that is one exabyte, assuming that you use 8 bits per point? Wow, you have a lot of RAM!

I think you should re-think your approach.